# How to set particular days of the week (Mondays, Tuesdays etc. ) in a different color in JQueryUI datepicker?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, datepicker

Is there a way to set particular days of the week (all Mondays, all Tuesdays for whole year etc. ) in a different color in JQueryUI datepicker?
I know there is built in methods to select specific dates, and there are ways to disable holidays, but I havent found a generic way to do such a task so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery UI datepicker doesn't add class names to specific days of the week, but you could use the css *nth-child* selector.

For example, if Sunday if the first day of the week in your calendar, the third cell will be Tuesday, which you can highlight like so:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr td:nth-child(5n+3) a {background: #FC0;}
```

In this example only the second table cell will be affected as the *(5n+3)* formula modified the multiples of five cells, offset by three.  The full pattern is 3, 8, 13, 18, 23, 28 etc but as there is only seven days, no other cells are changed.

This is a handy article for understanding how the nth child works - http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

jQuery can also use the nth-child formula which makes this approach cross-browser.

Comment: Works perfect, I did not new about nth-child, thank you so much!